# What does Quality affect, for the Mandatory Requests?

Tags: atelier-rorona

What does Quality affect, for the Mandatory Requests, like Assignment 1's Zettel, Polish Powder and Alchemy Coal?

Does it determine how much of a star I get for each item?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I played and I never learned the exact mechanics, but I believe you are graded on up to 3 different things:

1. Quantity of items
2. Cumulative quality of items
3. Suitability of items.

Quantity is self explanatory. Quality is definitely a factor, and I *believe* it is cumulative, unlike with alchemy. Delivering 4 quality 25 items should be the same as 1 quality 100 item *for that particular metric*.

Suitability is more vague and comes into play when the requested item is a class, rather than a specific item. This should work the same way as with alchemy - when creating a healing salve, depending on the items chosen, it may have the effect of HP Recovery XS, HP Recovery S, or HP Recovery M - item type and quality affect the items, which is shown as the bar during synthesis.

Early on, you won't have many options for improving your alchemy, so I'd recommend focusing on quantity.

Comment: The more I wrote this the more I questioned myself. I think the last sentence is perfectly accurate at least - eventually you'll be able to make 120 quality items with huge lists of traits... but very early on your options are extremely limited, so quantity is all you can do.